# '=' expected near var_y

Tags: syntax, lua

I have this code:

```
function var_leafdrop(var_inc, var_restpos)

     If var_y >= var_restpos then
        var_y = var_restpos
     else
        var_y = var_y + var_inc
     end

     return var_y

end
```

I get error:

> error 18: '=' expected near 'var_y'

18 being the line:

`If var_y >= var_restpos then`

I've tried:

- Changing the variable name
- Changing its declaration
- Removing the if then block
- Moving the entire function to the beginning of the script file

This is using the built in script editor for Watchmaker.

I can't see any error!? I just don't get it. Is this some dumb idiosyncrasy with Watchmaker...?

Comment: Unfortunately, Lua is not like Pascal (or SQL or any other case-insensitive-syntax language).  In Lua, `If` is not the same as `if`.  I frequently want to write `Function` in Lua, as I was doing in Pascal,  but Lua requires keywords to be lower-case. That means you can have variable with name `If` in Lua, but who needs such variable?

Comment: Thank you. I get it now. Now I'm having problems understanding Lua's variable permanence and how it handles globals...arrrghhhh

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Lua is case sensitive.
So use `if` instead of `If`.